# Listviewwebpart doesn't render the data and shows "Loading..."

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list-view-web-part

I have created a custom solution and used listviewwebpart to display the data. It works fine if I have only one webpart added on a page but as soon as I add another webpart the webpart start showing "Loading..." and stuck there.Below is my code for the same. I am taking weburl, list name and view name as an input from the user.

```
ListViewWebPart lvwp = new ListViewWebPart();
lvwp.ID = this.ID;
lvwp.Visible = true;
lvwp.EnableViewState = true;

SPList list = web.Lists[ListName.ToString()];                                

lvwp.ListName = list.ID.ToString("B").Trim().ToUpperInvariant();
lvwp.WebId = list.ParentWeb.ID;
lvwp.ListId = list.ID;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewName))
{
SPView defaultView = list.Views[ViewName];
lvwp.ViewId = Int32.Parse(defaultView.BaseViewID);
lvwp.ViewGuid = defaultView.ID.ToString("B").Trim().ToUpperInvariant();
}

lvwp.ChromeState = System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PartChromeState.Normal;
lvwp.ChromeType = System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PartChromeType.None;
lvwp.HelpMode = WebPartHelpMode.Modeless;

this.Controls.Add(lvwp);
```

Do anyone have any idea why is it happening. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you added `lvwp.EnableViewState = true;` so you will need to rebind data back to list on post back.

```
lvwp.DataSource = SomeData;
lvwp.DataBind();
```

Comment: I have tried this but didn't work. First time when I browse the page then the webpart shows the data but from 2nd time onwards it doesn't. :(